# Parametrizing the intersection of two ellipsoids to find arc length

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, parametrization, quadrics, ellipsoids

Suppose I have two ellipsoids in $\Bbb{R^3}$, with one centered at the origin and aligned to the coordinate axis, and the other in general position. I can represent these by:

$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$$
$$ \left[\vec{x}-\vec{v}\right]^TA\left[\vec{x}-\vec{v}\right] - 1 = 0 $$

where $\vec{x} = \left[x\ y\ z\ \right]^T$, $\vec{v} = \left[x_0\ y_0\ z_0\ \right]^T$ is the center of the ellipsoid in the general position, and $A = WGW^T$ such that $W$ is a matrix of the unit semi-axes of the ellipsoid as column vectors, and $G$ is a diagonal matrix containing the inverse of the squares of the length of the corresponding semi-axes of the ellipsoid along the diagonal.

The intersection of these two surfaces, if it exists, is a curve. This curve may be continuous, or contain two different segments, depending on whether one is partially "inside" the other.

Assuming that we have a continuous curve, and assuming we know two points on the curve, I would like to find the length of the curve between these two points.

From what I understand, to compute this I first need to find a suitable parametrization for the curve. However, I am struggling with how to go about doing this.

Solving for $z$ in one and then substituting into the other leads to a messy quartic of two variables, and it is not clear how to separate the variables or what parametrization would apply.

I tried expressing one in terms of spherical coordinates $\theta$ and $\phi$, and then substituting into the other. I still get an equation where it is not clear how to separate $\theta$ and $\phi$ and how I would go about parametrizing the result.

Am I approaching this the right way? How would I go about solving this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: This problem is unlikely to have a "nice" solution. Even simpler problems such as the perimeter of an ellipse are non-elementary.

Comment: @K.defaoite I will settle for any solution at this point... :P. Do you mean it won’t necessarily have a closed-form analytical solution?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Maybe I am using the wrong term. One would be an ellipsoid aligned to the coordinate axis, and the other would be in general position.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo gotcha. I updated the title.